# InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [index] not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, deployment, ovh

I want to deploy my laravel App with OVH hosting. When I'm opening my website I get this, someone knows why ?

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [index] not found.
```

here is Fileviewfinder

```
    <?php

namespace Illuminate\View;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class FileViewFinder implements ViewFinderInterface
{
    /**
     * The filesystem instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem
     */
    protected $files;

    /**
     * The array of active view paths.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $paths;

    /**
     * The array of views that have been located.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $views = [];

    /**
     * The namespace to file path hints.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hints = [];

    /**
     * Register a view extension with the finder.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $extensions = ['blade.php', 'php'];

    /**
     * Create a new file view loader instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem  $files
     * @param  array  $paths
     * @param  array  $extensions
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Filesystem $files, array $paths, array $extensions = null)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
        $this->paths = $paths;

        if (isset($extensions)) {
            $this->extensions = $extensions;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the fully qualified location of the view.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return string
     */
    public function find($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->views[$name])) {
            return $this->views[$name];
        }

        if ($this->hasHintInformation($name = trim($name))) {
            return $this->views[$name] = $this->findNamedPathView($name);
        }

        return $this->views[$name] = $this->findInPaths($name, $this->paths);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path to a template with a named path.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return string
     */
    protected function findNamedPathView($name)
    {
        list($namespace, $view) = $this->getNamespaceSegments($name);

        return $this->findInPaths($view, $this->hints[$namespace]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the segments of a template with a named path.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return array
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    protected function getNamespaceSegments($name)
    {
        $segments = explode(static::HINT_PATH_DELIMITER, $name);

        if (count($segments) != 2) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] has an invalid name.");
        }

        if (! isset($this->hints[$segments[0]])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("No hint path defined for [{$segments[0]}].");
        }

        return $segments;
    }

    /**
     * Find the given view in the list of paths.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array   $paths
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    protected function findInPaths($name, $paths)
    {
        foreach ((array) $paths as $path) {
            foreach ($this->getPossibleViewFiles($name) as $file) {
                if ($this->files->exists($viewPath = $path.'/'.$file)) {
                    return $viewPath;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found.");
    }

    /**
     * Get an array of possible view files.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPossibleViewFiles($name)
    {
        return array_map(function ($extension) use ($name) {
            return str_replace('.', '/', $name).'.'.$extension;

        }, $this->extensions);
    }

    /**
     * Add a location to the finder.
     *
     * @param  string  $location
     * @return void
     */
    public function addLocation($location)
    {
        $this->paths[] = $location;
    }

    /**
     * Add a namespace hint to the finder.
     *
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @param  string|array  $hints
     * @return void
     */
    public function addNamespace($namespace, $hints)
    {
        $hints = (array) $hints;

        if (isset($this->hints[$namespace])) {
            $hints = array_merge($this->hints[$namespace], $hints);
        }

        $this->hints[$namespace] = $hints;
    }

    /**
     * Prepend a namespace hint to the finder.
     *
     * @param  string  $namespace
     * @param  string|array  $hints
     * @return void
     */
    public function prependNamespace($namespace, $hints)
    {
        $hints = (array) $hints;

        if (isset($this->hints[$namespace])) {
            $hints = array_merge($hints, $this->hints[$namespace]);
        }

        $this->hints[$namespace] = $hints;
    }

    /**
     * Register an extension with the view finder.
     *
     * @param  string  $extension
     * @return void
     */
    public function addExtension($extension)
    {
        if (($index = array_search($extension, $this->extensions)) !== false) {
            unset($this->extensions[$index]);
        }

        array_unshift($this->extensions, $extension);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the view specify a hint information.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasHintInformation($name)
    {
        return strpos($name, static::HINT_PATH_DELIMITER) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the filesystem instance.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem
     */
    public function getFilesystem()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }

    /**
     * Get the active view paths.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPaths()
    {
        return $this->paths;
    }

    /**
     * Get the namespace to file path hints.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getHints()
    {
        return $this->hints;
    }

    /**
     * Get registered extensions.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getExtensions()
    {
        return $this->extensions;
    }
}
```

Comment: post that code ?? how we will know what is in `FileViewFinder.php line 137` ?

Comment: Edited post above sorry

Comment: can you tell which is line number 137 ??

Comment: throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found.");

Comment: may be because the space in `View [$name]` if View is an array .

Comment: Doesn't change anything, i also get "at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('index', array('C:\wamp\www\project\resources\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79, but that link is local. I don't understand why

Comment: `var_dump($name);  exit;`  before the line 137 let me know what you got

Comment: that should be something else ??  or you need to handle it using try catch.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant.. Im supposed to get my index.blade.php view

Answer (score 1):

Run the command "php artisan config:clear"
Then request again and a new "config.php" file will be created in "./bootstrap/cache/config.php" with the app settings

Answer (score 1):

> - php artisan cache:clear
> - php artisan view:clear
> - php artisan config:cache

you should fix try this laravel command.It's will be okay.thanks..

[`deployment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deployment)
[`laravel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-5.1)
[`ovh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ovh)